# Can I send a string to grep with commands and file names in a bash script?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, grep

Is it possible to send an array variable from the command line,

(where `argsGrep="$@"` and the command line input is something to the extent of -i Something) to a grep command

e.g.

```
result=$(grep $argsGrep ./file)
```

When `$argsGrep` has only the term to be searched, it works just fine, but the moment it contains more than the text and has a grep command, I can't get it to work whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use the intermediate string. It will just break things.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Just expand `"$@"` at the point you need it.

If you **must** save the contents of `"$@"` for some reason then you **must** use another array.

```
argsarr=("$@")

result=$(grep "${argsarr[@]}" ./file)
```